# Current recommended technique for cache-busting Aurelia (SystemJS-based) apps

Tags: browser-cache, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I've found scattered github issues and articles about cache-busting Aurelia and SystemJS apps; however, I haven't had 100% success with those.  One systemjs plugin technique had side-effects of tacking on a url param twice.  Also, url params do not seem to gaurantee that cached resources are not used on all browsers.

The best, 100% solid solution from my perspective would be to deploy the app to a different path.  For example, tack the version and build time into the url **path**, https://my.domain.com/v1.0.0b20161011_120001/index.html, https://my.domain.com/v1.0.0b20161011_120122/index.html

What is the current recommended technique, plugin or other process for cache-busting Aurelia apps?

Comment: @CasiOo in Aurelia/Discuss gitter channel recommended setting rev: true in the bundles.js.  This seems to work.  I'm not 100% confident about it yet simply because I haven't thoroughly tested.  I'll follow-up after letting it ride for a while.

Comment: Michael Prescott's comment above worked for me.  For the answer, I think this should be the first thing to try before resorting the more involved solutions outlined by Darxtar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force your Aurelia app to be constantly refreshed after you modify it, you can have a look at the following thread:

https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/94

Aaike commented on 8 May 2015:

> change your index.html to add the extension right before you import
>   the aurelia-bootstrapper

```
<script>
      var systemLocate = System.locate;
      System.locate = function(load) {
        var System = this;
        return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, load)).then(function(address) {
          if(address.lastIndexOf("html.js") > -1) return address;
          if(address.lastIndexOf("css.js") > -1) return address;
          return address + System.cacheBust;
        });
      };
      System.cacheBust = '?bust=' + Date.now();

      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

You can also make a gulp task that appends a version number to your bundled files, as suggested by shaunluttin in the https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/94 thread.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var fs = require("fs");

var buildNumberFile = 'build/build-number.txt';

var filesToChange = [
    'build/bundles.js',
    'build/paths.js',
    'config.js',
    'package.json'
];

gulp.task('cache-bust', function () {

    // get the current build number
    var contents = fs.readFileSync(buildNumberFile, 'utf8');
    version = parseInt(contents);

    // bump the current build number
    version = version + 1;
    fs.writeFile(buildNumberFile, version);

    // 
    // matches "dist
    // matches 'dist
    // matches "dist1
    // matches 'dist12
    // 
    var outputDirectoryRegex = /([\"|\']dist)([0-9]*)/g;

    // replace the build number in appropriate files
    gulp.src(filesToChange, { base: './' })
        .pipe(replace(outputDirectoryRegex, '$1' + version))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 does not entirely work but
Option 2 works for me. I just had to change the outputDirectoryRegEx to

```
var outputDirectoryRegex = /([\"|\'|\\|\/]dist)([0-9]*)/g;
```

since mine is inside wwwroot/